# Finding all non-comparable nodes in DAG

Tags: boost, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

I am interested in finding sets of vertices that are not ordered in a directed acyclic graph (in the sense of a topological order).

That is, for example: two vertices in non-connected subgraphs, or the pairs (B,C), (B,D) in cases such as :
[image: a graph]

The naive possibility I thought of was to enumerate all the topological sorts (in this case `[ A, B, C, D ]` and `[ A, C, D, B ]` & find all pairs whose order ends up being different in at least two sorts, but this would be pretty expensive computationally.

Are there other, faster possibilities for what I want to achieve ? I am using boost.graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is the pair of nodes `(u,v)` such that there is no path from u to v, and no path from v to u. You can find for each node, all nodes that are reachable from that node using DFS. Total Complexity `O(n(n+m))`.

Now all you have to do is for each pair check if neither of the 2 nodes are reachable by the other.

Comment: And as a lower bound, in the worst case there are Omega(n^2) pairs of nodes that aren't reachable from one another. I wonder if you can improve on your O(nm + n^2)-time algorithm to get one that runs in worst-case time O(n^2), matching that lower bound.

Comment: @templatetypedef I tried but that's the best complexity I could come up with, I'd be interested if someone provides a better complexity

Comment: hmmm.. that's what I had been doing at the beginning and due to a misuse of boost.graph I became convinced that this was not the way to go... but indeed after fixing the bugs it works !

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a simple topological sort. Boost's implementation conveniently returns a reverse ordered list of vertices.

You can iterate that list, marking each initial leaf node with a new branch id until a shared node is encountered.

### Demo Time

Let's start with the simplests of graph models:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;
```

We wish to map branches:

```
using BranchID = int;
using BranchMap = std::vector<BranchID>; // maps vertex id -> branch id
```

We want to build, map and visualize the mappings:

```
Graph     build();
BranchMap map_branches(Graph const&);
void      visualize(Graph const&, BranchMap const& branch_map);

int main() {
    // sample data
    Graph g = build();

    // do the topo sort and distinguish branches
    BranchMap mappings = map_branches(g);

    // output
    visualize(g, mappings);
}
```

### Building Graph

Just the sample data from the question:

```
Graph build() {
    Graph g(4);

    enum {A,B,C,D};
    add_edge(A, B, g);
    add_edge(A, C, g);
    add_edge(C, D, g);

    return g;
}
```

### Mapping The Branches

As described in the introduction:

```
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>

std::vector<BranchID> map_branches(Graph const& g) {
    std::vector<Vertex> reverse_topo;
    boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(reverse_topo));

    // traverse the output to map to unique branch ids
    std::vector<BranchID> branch_map(num_vertices(g));

    BranchID branch_id = 0;

    for (auto v : reverse_topo) {
        auto degree = out_degree(v, g);
        if (0 == degree) // is leaf?
            ++branch_id;

        if (degree < 2) // "unique" path
            branch_map[v] = branch_id;
    }

    return branch_map;
}
```

### Visualizing

Let's write a graph-viz representation with each branch colored:

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void visualize(Graph const& g, BranchMap const& branch_map) {
    // display helpers
    std::vector<std::string> const colors { "gray", "red", "green", "blue" };

    auto name = [](Vertex v) -> char { return 'A'+v; };
    auto color = [&](Vertex v) -> std::string { return colors[branch_map.at(v) % colors.size()]; };

    // write graphviz:
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", transform(name));
    dp.property("color", transform(color));

    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

This uses a tiny shorthand helper to create the transforming property maps:

```
// convenience short-hand to write transformed property maps
template <typename F>
static auto transform(F f) { return boost::make_transform_value_property_map(f, boost::identity_property_map{}); };
```

> To compile this on a non-c++14 compiler you can replace the call to `transform` with the expanded body

## Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d08efad122c2e02a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;

using BranchID = int;
using BranchMap = std::vector<BranchID>; // maps vertex id -> branch id

Graph     build();
BranchMap map_branches(Graph const&);
void      visualize(Graph const&, BranchMap const& branch_map);

int main() {
    // sample data
    Graph g = build();

    // do the topo sort and distinguish branches
    BranchMap mappings = map_branches(g);

    // output
    visualize(g, mappings);
}

using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

Graph build() {
    Graph g(4);

    enum {A,B,C,D};
    add_edge(A, B, g);
    add_edge(A, C, g);
    add_edge(C, D, g);

    return g;
}

#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>

std::vector<BranchID> map_branches(Graph const& g) {
    std::vector<Vertex> reverse_topo;
    boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(reverse_topo));

    // traverse the output to map to unique branch ids
    std::vector<BranchID> branch_map(num_vertices(g));

    BranchID branch_id = 0;

    for (auto v : reverse_topo) {
        auto degree = out_degree(v, g);
        if (0 == degree) // is leaf?
            ++branch_id;

        if (degree < 2) // "unique" path
            branch_map[v] = branch_id;
    }

    return branch_map;
}

#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>

// convenience short-hand to write transformed property maps
template <typename F>
static auto transform(F f) { return boost::make_transform_value_property_map(f, boost::identity_property_map{}); };

#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void visualize(Graph const& g, BranchMap const& branch_map) {
    // display helpers
    std::vector<std::string> const colors { "gray", "red", "green", "blue" };

    auto name = [](Vertex v) -> char { return 'A'+v; };
    auto color = [&](Vertex v) -> std::string { return colors[branch_map.at(v) % colors.size()]; };

    // write graphviz:
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", transform(name));
    dp.property("color", transform(color));

    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

Printing

```
digraph G {
A [color=gray];
B [color=red];
C [color=green];
D [color=green];
A->B ;
A->C ;
C->D ;
}
```

And the rendered graph:

[image]

## Summary

Nodes in branches with different colors cannot be compared.

Comment: I tried editing the edges on Coliru to make the graph with edges A=>C, B=>C, C=>D, the output is that all nodes are red, however the pair (A,B) is not ordered. Did I do something wrong? This is the link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04b781e6f833c3be

Comment: Hah. I failed to realize it could be a DAG as opposed to the tree that was used as an example. The [difference being, of course that there could be multiple parents for a node](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16046dd01b4fbf51). That's a workaround based on a [`BidirectionalGraph` (as opposed to a strict `AdjacencyGraph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html). I'm going to have to think a bit more for a generalized solution. I think it's not correct in all cases yet